# displaying picture from xml document

Tags: xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, imaging

hello i have a problem in getting picture from the url contained in the xml file:

```
<item>
    <title>Music</title>
    <photo>http://www.jawharafm.net/jfmfiles/photos/hamdi.jpg</photo>
</item>
```

and here's my code c#:

```
XElement xmlItems = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

listBox1.ItemsSource = from channel in xmlItems.Descendants("item")

let tit = channel.Element("title")

let pho = channel.Element("photo")

select new items
{
    title = tit == null ? null : tit.Value,
    photo = pho == null ? null : pho.Value,
};
```

also i have a small problem in ignoring style balise in displaying text after parsing document like this :

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[<style>img { max-width: 310px; }</style><div>un concours mondial, appelé           "BlueHat"</span>, pour récompenser le ou la passionné d'informatique capable  <span    style="color: #3366ff;">10.000 dollars</span>.</div>
        <div /><span style="color: #ffffff;" />....]]>
</description>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right where you are using the ternary operators for the photo, you need to create an instance of a `BitmapImage`. Something like this:

```
photo = pho == null ? null : new BitmapImage(new Uri(pho.Value))
```

Given that `photo` is a `BitmapImage` itself.

What exactly is the problem with the style tag? Since you are declaring it as a part of `CDATA`, it is correctly read and interpreted as a standard string value.

Comment: in the screen it returns all the contain of description like urls and style ...i just want to ignore them and get the interrest part !

Comment: Does it have a predictable pattern? E.g. do you know that it will start with a style? Are there more DIVs inside?

Comment: I would recommend trying REGEX, but that could be a bit of a pain to learn.